# "Unknown column 'tag_tag_id' in 'field list'" error on Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `Tag` model like this :

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_id';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'taggable');
    }
}
```

And On the other hand there is a Product model like this :

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    protected $fillable = ['code', 'title', 'description'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(\Modules\Tag\Entities\Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }

}
```

As You can see there is a **many mo many polymorphic relations** between them . But each time I want to store a product that have some tags like this :

```
public function store(ProductFormRequest $request)
{
    $newProduct = Product::create($request->all());

    if ($request->has('tags')) {
        $newProduct->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));
    }

    return $this->item($newProduct, new ProductTransformer);
}
```

I got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tag_tag_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tag_tag_id` from `taggables` where `taggable_id` = 4 and `taggable_type` = Modules\\Product\\Entities\\Product)
```

What is problem and How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Many To Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations):

```
products
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

As you can see, the default "tag ID" column in `taggables` table is `tag_id`. This means, `the name of the table in the singular` + `_` + `primary key name`. Since you specify your primary key as `tag_id`, the query is searching for `tag_tag_id`.

You have two solutions:

1) Stick to the convention and use the default `id` as your primary keys.

2) Pass a parameter to `morphToMany` specifying that the primaryKey is `tag_id`. Here you have all the parameters that accepts the `morphToMany` method: [MorphToMany API](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_morphToMany).

I'm not sure which one is the correct (I think is $relatedPivotKey), but you should try ($foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey, $parentKey or $relatedKey). Pass the default values for the ones you are not changing.

Something like this: `$this->morphToMany(\Modules\Tag\Entities\Tag::class, 'taggable', null, null, 'tag_id');`

Comment: Problem is that exactly I do not know which parameter in `morphToMany` should be changed?on the other hand I do not change primary key on `Tag` model beacause I used it in many places

Comment: @A.B.Developer :  did you check the [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_morphedByMany) provided

Comment: @A.B.Developer just try each parameter until it works, I think `$relatedPivotKey` is the one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It was not useful beacause api only listed parameters and not provided any description of them

Comment: @A.B.Developer if you click on the method's name, you get a description of the properties: [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphToMany.html) and if you click the link that says `line 343` you can see the code [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L343).

Comment: I used `return $this->morphToMany(\Modules\Tag\Entities\Tag::class,'taggable', null, null, null, 'tag_id'); but same error occured
`

Comment: @A.B.Developer keep trying, I believe in you.

Comment: Now I used `return $this->morphToMany(\Modules\Tag\Entities\Tag::class, 'taggable', null, null, 'tag_id');` and problem is solved!